# ggplot: how to add an outline around each fill in a stacked barchart but only partly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have the following stacked barchart produced with `geom_bar`.

**Question:** how to add an outline around each `fill` corresponding to the matched color in `cols`. The tricky part is, that the outline should not be in between each `fill` but around the "borders" and the top, exclusively (expected output below)

I have

[image]

Written with

```
library(ggplot)
cols = c("#E1B930", "#2C77BF","#E38072","#6DBCC3", "grey40","black")

ggplot(i, aes(fill=uicc, x=n)) + theme_bw() +

  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="count") +

  scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(cols,0.5))
```

Expected output

[image]

My data `i`

```
i <- structure(list(uicc = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), n = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a way.

There's no easy way to draw just the "outside" lines, so the approach I used was to go ahead and draw them with the `geom_bar` call.  The inner lines are "erased" by drawing white rectangles over top the initial `geom_bar` call, and then the fill is drawn back in with a colorless `color=` aesthetic.

In order to draw the rectangles over the initial `geom_bar` call, I created a summary dataframe of `i` which sets the y values.

```
i.sum <- i %>% group_by(n) %>% tally()

ggplot(i, aes(x=n)) + theme_bw() +

  # draw lines
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='count',
      aes(color=uicc), fill=NA, size=1.5) +

  # cover over those inner lines
  geom_col(data=i.sum, aes(y=nn), fill='white') +

  # put back in the fill
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='count',
      aes(fill=uicc), color=NA) +

  scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(cols,0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cols)
```

Note that the `size=` of the `color=` aesthetic needs to be much higher than normal, since the white rectangle ends up covering about half the line.

[image]

Comment: Hi @chemdork123. Perfect! Thank you very much. Best